Convert CH1903+/LV95 projection (EPSG:2056) to EPSG:4326 (WGS84) with vertical correction
I am currently trying to use elevation data data from the Swiss Alti3D DEM and compare it to another set of data that I have acquired in WGS 84 (EPSG: 4326). As such, I tried to reproject the Swiss Alti3D DEM to WGS 84 to match my data. However, I quickly noticed that the reprojected elevation raster was not correct since a vertical correction is needed for height data. I tried looking for solutions using gdal and Python but I do not have a grid that can be used to reproject the data from the Swiss LV95 LN02 projection to WGS84 EPSG 4326.
My initial approach was to use a gdal.Warp function, using a reference raster (in 4326) to reproject the target raster (Swiss Alti3D) as follows:
from osgeo import gdal

def match_resolution(reference_raster: str, target_raster: str, resampling_alg: str = "cubic"):
    """
    Warps the target raster to match the resolution of the reference raster using GDAL's Warp function.
    
    Parameters:
    - reference_raster: str, path to the raster file whose resolution you want to match.
    - target_raster: str, path to the raster file that needs to be warped.
    - output_raster: str, path to the output raster file where the result will be saved.
    - resampling_alg: str, resampling algorithm to use (default is 'cubic').
      Other options include 'nearest', 'bilinear', etc.
    """
    
    # Open the reference raster to get its resolution
    ref_ds = gdal.Open(reference_raster)
    if ref_ds is None:
        raise ValueError(f"Unable to open reference raster: {reference_raster}")
    
    # Get the geotransform and dimensions of the reference raster
    ref_geotransform = ref_ds.GetGeoTransform()
    ref_proj = ref_ds.GetProjection()
    ref_x_res = ref_geotransform[1]  # Pixel width (resolution in x direction)
    ref_y_res = abs(ref_geotransform[5])  # Pixel height (resolution in y direction)
    
    # Close the reference dataset
    ref_ds = None
    
    # Set up the warp options to match the resolution of the reference raster
    warp_options = gdal.WarpOptions(
        format="GTiff",
        xRes=ref_x_res,  # Resolution in x-direction from reference raster
        yRes=ref_y_res,  # Resolution in y-direction from reference raster
        resampleAlg=resampling_alg,  # Resampling algorithm (e.g., cubic, bilinear, nearest, etc.)
        dstSRS=ref_proj
    )
    output_raster = target_raster.replace(".tif", "_rm-12m-4326.tif")
    # Perform the warp on the target raster
    gdal.Warp(destNameOrDestDS=output_raster, srcDSOrSrcDSTab=target_raster, options=warp_options)
    
    print(f"Warped raster saved to: {output_raster}")

After running the code above for my case, a bias of around 50 meters appeared, and then I realized that the Swiss DEM data need to be vertically corrected by a grid. I tried my best and I could not find any sort of grid that I could use to vertically adjust the data when reprojecting. Furthermore, I struggled to see how could I solve this issue with gdal or any other library (maybe proj?) in Python. Any help is immensely appreciated!
In case it is helpful, here is the full projection of the Swiss 3D DEM data as per gdal:
'PROJCS["CH1903+ / LV95",GEOGCS["CH1903+",DATUM["CH1903+",SPHEROID["Bessel 1841",6377397.155,299.1528128,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7004"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6150"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4150"]],PROJECTION["Hotine_Oblique_Mercator_Azimuth_Center"],PARAMETER["latitude_of_center",46.9524055555556],PARAMETER["longitude_of_center",7.43958333333333],PARAMETER["azimuth",90],PARAMETER["rectified_grid_angle",90],PARAMETER["scale_factor",1],PARAMETER["false_easting",2600000],PARAMETER["false_northing",1200000],UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],AXIS["Easting",EAST],AXIS["Northing",NORTH],AUTHORITY["EPSG","2056"]]'


Are you sure you get wrong results? Elevation on WGS84 is particular (and the 50 meters seems you are correct: alps push gravity) (particular as not very useful). GPS devices may use better corrections (so not on WGS84 geoid)

Thank you for your comment, Giacomo. While I see your point, I still have to put all of the data in the same coordinate system and projection for fair comparisons. For my current project, WGS84 is preferable.

But my point is: are you sure you do not get correct WGS84 altitude? (so that the other data uses a different vertical datum). The 50 meters seems similar to the difference between WGS84 ellipsoid and a various geoids. So check again your data, about the vertical datum (we usually just write about horizontal datum). Note that also Swiss coordinates where updated (both horizontally and vertically, but at different time and so with mixed cases: but that should have just effects about few meters).
